# Vaadin Layout - how to get a panel to expand to fill most of the screen

Tags: java, layout, vaadin

Please note I'm Using Vaadin for this.

I'm struggling to get the middle panel to expand to fill most of the screen with a header and footer at the top and bottom respectively. Here's my code:

```
public class GridpocApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void init() {
    System.out.println("starting now.");

    final Window mainWindow = new Window("My Application");
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);

    mainWindow.getContent().setSizeFull();

    VerticalLayout mainColumn = new VerticalLayout();
    //Header
    Label top = new Label("HEADER");
    mainColumn.addComponent(top);

    //The middle bit
    final Panel middlePanel = new Panel();
    middlePanel.setSizeFull();
    middlePanel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();
    middlePanel.setScrollable(true);
    mainColumn.addComponent(middlePanel);
    mainColumn.setExpandRatio(middlePanel, 1.0f);

    //footer
    Label bottom = new Label("FOOTER");
    mainColumn.addComponent(bottom);
    mainWindow.addComponent(mainColumn);

    //test
    Label test= new Label("This area should fill most of the screen.");
    middlePanel.addComponent(test);
}
}
```

Where am I going wrong? What I see is this:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making `mainColumn.setSizeFull()` and `mainWindow.setContent(mainColumn)`

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thnk you're basically right - the real problem was that I wasn't setting the mainWindow's content to the mainColumn and it already had a VerticalLayout (by default). Once I did that and set one of the children with 'setSizeFull', it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Charles Anthony great, could you also look this one; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910302/vaadin-table-does-not-update-no-matter-what-i-try