# Vaadin Table does not update no matter what I try

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I use Vaadin (6.7.4) and this table **(it is on a modal window)** does not update the view.

First it was created with generated columns, but I read that it has problems with table update, so I switched back to normal table, but still no  refresh.

Updatedata is called by button click event on the panel

```
final Table table = new Table();
final IndexedContainer ic=new IndexedContainer();

public createTable(){
    table.setImmediate(true);   
    table.setEnabled(true); 
    ic.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class,  null);
    ic.addContainerProperty("Edit", Button.class, null);
    ic.addContainerProperty("Delete", Button.class,  null);
    table.setContainerDataSource(ic);
}

public void addItems(Table table) {
    for (String s : createdNames) {
        ic.addItem(s);
        ic.getItem(s).getItemProperty("Name").setValue(s);
        ic.getItem(s).getItemProperty("Edit").setValue("Edit");
        ic.getItem(s).getItemProperty("Delete").setValue("Delete");
    }

}

public void updateData() {      
    IndexedContainer c=(IndexedContainer) table.getContainerDataSource();
    c.removeAllItems();
    c.addItem("myname");
    c.getContainerProperty("myname", "Name").setValue("Mr.X");
    table.setContainerDataSource(c);
    table.refreshRowCache();
    table.requestRepaint();
    System.out.println("see the output but no update on table");
}
```

Edit: turned out problem is not about this code, but this class was instantiated 2 times, so I had different instances; the one i am updating and the one I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete Vaadin application that works:

```
public class TableTest extends Application {
final Table table = new Table();
final IndexedContainer ic = new IndexedContainer();

@Override
public void init() {
    setMainWindow(new Window("Window"));
    createTable();
    getMainWindow().addComponent(table);
    getMainWindow().addComponent(
            new Button("Click me", new Button.ClickListener() {
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    updateData();
                }
            }));
}

public void createTable() {
    table.setImmediate(true);
    table.setEnabled(true);
    ic.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
    ic.addContainerProperty("Edit", Button.class, null);
    ic.addContainerProperty("Delete", Button.class, null);
    table.setContainerDataSource(ic);
}

public void updateData() {
    ic.removeAllItems();
    ic.addItem("myname");
    ic.getContainerProperty("myname", "Name").setValue("Mr.X");
    System.out.println("see the output but no update on table");
}
}
```

It seems that the problem is somewhere else in your code. By the way, in the future you should create a completely new application from scratch to isolate the problem and validate that it is where you think it is.

Comment: thanks but this is all the code related with the table, any suggestion where should I check for the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's practically impossible to deduce the problem without seeing the rest of your code. However, a wild guess: is the createTable() method called in error every time after updateData()?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the main window to static:

```
public static Window win = new Window("Window");
setMainWindow(win);
```

This should help.